# iPhone - Check if character is capital

Tags: iphone, nsstring

Hey!  I was wondering if there was any way to check if the first letter of a string was capital or not in an NSString.  Something similar to:

```
if ([[string substringToIndex:1] isCapitalLetter]) {
    // CODE
}
```

--or--

```
if ([self isCapitalLetter:[string substringToIndex:1]]) {
    // CODE
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`[[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[myString characterAtIndex:0]];`

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of would be to do something like this:

```
// get the first character, capitalized
NSString *capital = [[oldstring substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString];

// then compare to your oldstring
if ( [[oldstring substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:capital] ) {
    // do stuff...
}
```

The NSString reference is your friend: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html